# correlation of the sums of samples

Tags: statistics, correlation

Given variables $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, if $n$ samples are randomly selected from $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and summed to obtain new variables $X_1$ and $Y_1$, are $X_1$ and $Y_1$ necessarily positively correlated?

Comment: What have you tried?  In effect you are asking whether $\text{Cov}(X,Y)\gt 0$ implies $\text{Cov}(X_a+X_b+\cdots+X_n,Y_a+Y_b+\cdots+Y_n)\gt 0$ and you might want to consider the bilinearity of covariance.  Divide by the product of the standard deviations to get correlation